# Grub2 Unable to be installed on SSD-usb partition for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on an x86 64bit architecture, and I am trying to install grub2 onto a USB partition that I made on my SSD card. According to the Disks application, the partitioning is `GUID Partition Table`. I allocated 100GB on the 1TB SSD card for a Lubuntu ISO installation on the `/dev/sdc2` partition: [image]

I also ran Gparted, and it shows sdc2 as fat32, with boot,esp flags set, and with label `GRUB2EFI`.
I am trying to follow this guide on how to boot Lubuntu from USB, but the grub2 installation is failing when I try running `sudo grub-install --removable --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --efi-directory=/mnt/EFI/BOOT /dev/sdc2`:https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276498

It returns `` grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/mnt/EFI/BOOT' ``. I also have tried this guide (https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) to chroot into /dev/sdc2 mount point and run grub-install, but `sudo chroot /mnt` fails and returns `chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`. I have made sure to format the drive as fat32 before trying to install grub, and the drive has been wiped clean each and every time before each attempt. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can only have one ESP - efi system partiiton. You can have another FAT32 partition if desired. In gparted right click and make sure only one FAT32 partition have esp, boot flags set.https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631048/how-to-install-grub-to-empty-disk-from-ubuntu-livecd/631107#631107 If installing the live installer, not a full install, be very careful what tools your use. Most just assume smaller flash drives and totally erase entire drive. Those that use dd convert first 2+GB of drive to hybrid DVD/flash configuration removing partition table.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. oldfred has helped greatly by helping me realize that `/dev/sdc1` was also mounted with `boot,esp` flags set. I unset these flags, followed the below guides, and Lubuntu booted from HDD somehow. It is good enough, but completely ignored my SDD 100gb partition (oops...).
2. When rebooting to grub2 rescue CLI, this helped very much: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot/330852
3. This guide also helped a lot to install grub2 on the Lubuntu partition, but make sure to look at all of the answers/edits: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276498

--> Also they have odd ways of unzipping files to a directory, just do this instead: `unzip usb-pack_efi.zip -d /mnt/`

4. I didn't edit any `grub.cfg` files, so grub2 boot-menu showed my Lubuntu as Ubuntu partition. Still works.
5. How to burn ISO file to USB: https://www.howtogeek.com/414574/how-to-burn-an-iso-file-to-a-usb-drive-in-linux/
6. Secure boot mode was disabled.